# how to show context menu when i click on left mouse button c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried this code but it didn't work please help

```
if(e.Buttons == MouseButton.left){
    contextMenu Menu_one = new contextMenu();
    var menu_item_copy = new MenuItem("Copy", menu_item_copy_click)
    Menu_one.Menuitem.add(menu_item_copy );
    button_one.contextMenu = Menu_one;
}
```

Comment: You need to show the menu after you add it to the control.

Comment: thx for your reply, can you give small example please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void button_one_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button is MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        button_one.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        button_one.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Copy", menu_item_copy_click);

        button_one.ContextMenu.Show(button_one, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}

private void menu_item_copy_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

Comment: Next you're probably going to need to add an event handler for the menu item. Since clicking it will do nothing without it.

Comment: I added an event handler example.

Comment: There's an issue in the code snippet for this

 `button_one.ContextMenu.Add("Copy", menu_item_copy_click);` 
should read `button_one.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Copy", menu_item_copy_click);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(e.Buttons == MouseButton.left){
    contextMenu Menu_one = new contextMenu();
    var menu_item_copy = new MenuItem("Copy", menu_item_copy_click)
    Menu_one.Menuitem.add(menu_item_copy );
    button_one.contextMenu = Menu_one;
    Menu_one.Show();
}
```

this is the line you forgot:
  Menu_one.Show();

Answer (score 0):

```
 button_one.ContextMenu.Show(button_one, new Point(e.X, e.Y), LeftRightAlignment.Right);
```

Comment: You have to explain how does this code works compared to the problem asked in the question. That way it would be more helpful for the other readers.